# app freezes on executeFetchRequest

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, core-data

I'm fetching data from core using the method below. My app freezes on

```
      NSArray *fetchResult = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes it just freeze without error messages or crashes. When I pause the debugger, it stops on the above line of code! I'm not using threads nor blocks.

```
-(NSArray *)getSubContent
{
NSEntityDescription *desc;
NSPredicate *predicate;
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
switch ([tableSelector selectedSegmentIndex])
{
    case 0: //fav list 
        desc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isFavorite = %@",[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
        sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
        break;
    case 1:  //Rassayel list
        desc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isApp = %@",[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
        break;
    case 2: //group list
        desc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Group" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        predicate = nil;
        sortDescriptor = nil;
        break;


    default:
        break;
}

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setEntity:desc];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchResult = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if ( error )
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
return fetchResult;

}
```

**CRASH LOG**

> Exception Type:  00000020 Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d Highlighted Thread:  0
>
> Application Specific Information: com.takarub.rasayl failed to launch
>   in time
>
> Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 1.620 (user 1.620, system 0.000), 3%
>   CPU  Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.432, 1% CPU
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Thread 0:
>
> 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x32b800d8 __psynch_mutexwait + 24
>
> 1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x34eaa674 pthread_mutex_lock + 376
>
> 2   CoreData                          0x327dbd52 -[_PFLock lock] + 18
>
> 3   CoreData                          0x327eb1f2
>   -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 806
>
> 4   CoreData                          0x327e9c22 -[NSManagedObjectContext
>   executeFetchRequest:error:] + 598
>
> 5   RassayelV1.0                      0x000193ec -[ContactsViewController
>   getSubContent] (ContactsViewController.m:225)

Comment: what is the value of the `selectedSegmentIndex` when your application crashed?

Comment: Have you figured this out?  I'm getting a similar issue.  Thnx.

Comment: @Jeremy the problem was related to me using the NSManagedObjectContext in more than one thread, it wasn't related to the code in this question.

Comment: Thanks @ahmad.  I've since discovered that my issue was related to using the Reachability object from within the applicationDidBecomeActive delegate method, which in some cases could be quite slow causing the watchdog to kill the app.  It was purely coincidental that my app crashed on similar lines of code.

Comment: You should use concurrency control in coredata fetch to avoid blocking of main thread. Best example is available [here](http://www.sebastianrehnby.com/blog/2013/05/20/using-background-fetching-with-core-data/)